# data gathering how was this done?

Tags: php, database, api

I'd love to understand how and where this website gets it's data from:
http://elophant.com/developers/docs
I find it hard to believe that the game developers just hand all this data in realtime(or close to) to elophant's developer.
how was he able to retrieve the information about games in progress for example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the note in the footer, "Images and Data graciously provided by Riot Inc."

I presume it's as stated here on a similar site: http://www.leagueofstats.com/faq

> Where do you get your data from?
>   We get our data from the Riot servers. Basically, we pretend to be the League of Legends client, and we use the "Lookup Player" feature to download your recent games, ranked stats, etc.

Comment: Thank you. didn't know that http://www.leagueofstats.com site. how would one pretend to be a client? you build a smll application on your server that sends some request to riots client server ip with specific headers or something like that?

Comment: I have no idea, not knowing anything about these games. My guess is that you send them HTTP requests of one sort or another and parse the returned data...